# Intentionally fail Ant build when using <delete> with a <fileset> including missing files

Tags: ant

```
<delete includeEmptyDirs="false" failonerror="true">    
    <fileset dir="${dest.dir}" includes="a.txt,b.txt,c.abc"/>
</delete>
```

For example, if file `a.txt` is changed to `a1.txt2` or something then Ant is not failing to find file. What to do?

Comment: <delete includeEmptyDirs="false" failonerror="true">  <fileset dir="${dest.dir}"
        includes="a.txt,b.txt, c.abc
        "/>

    </delete> is the code

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! This question could benefit from some improved formatting -- in the future, try not to put multiple sentences in the title. Also, it's best to include more complete code samples -- especially, grammatically unbalanced code samples can be quite hard to decipher.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the purpose of failonerror attribute in this case.
From [ant manual delete task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html) :

> Controls whether an error (**such as a failure to delete a file**)
>   stops the build or is merely reported to the screen. Only relevant if
>   quiet is "false".

It's not an error, if fileset doesn't match.
Also you don't need to set failonerror=true as it is default.
To make it fail, use [fail](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html) with [condition](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) and [resourcecount](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/resourcecount.html), f.e.:

```
<delete includeEmptyDirs="false" failonerror="true">    
 <fileset dir="${dest.dir}" includes="a.txt,b.txt,c.abc" id="foobar"/>
</delete>

<fail message="Fileset doesn't match !">
 <condition>
  <resourcecount when="eq" count="0">
   <fileset refid="foobar"/>
  </resourcecount>
 </condition>
</fail>
```